# Formula for a Calculated Field in MS Sharepoint that provides a timestamp based on the Status field value

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2007

**Goal**:

- 3 fields titled "Assigned Date", "Ready for Review Date", and
  "Submitted Date".
- When a user changes the Internal Status field to
  "Assigned", the "Assigned Date" field should update with a timestamp.
- When the same record's status is then later changed to "Ready for
  Review", the "Ready for Review Date" is updated with a timestamp
  while the "Assigned Date" timestamp remains un-changed.

**Limitation**: Unfortunately, I cannot create a customized workflow. Otherwise I wouldn't really be asking. My team is limited. We cannot access any other software / UI besides SharePoint online or InfoPath. There's no going around this. I know, it's redic.

**My Attempts**:

- I tried using InfoPath where I added an Action Rule (Set Field's
  Value). However, for me, this only worked when adding records. But
  for existing records, when I change the status in the Datasheet View,
  the timestamp fields did not update. Also, my team does not operate
  in webforms. We create and update the list in the Database View.
- I tried using a typical formula. See formula below. However, the
  timestamp output from the formula changes when the status changes. I
  need it to be a timestamp. See formula I used below:

=IF(Status="Sent to Client",TEXT(NOW(),"dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mm"),IF(ISBLANK(Status),"","NULL"))

I'm thinking this request is kind of impossible without using a Workflow. But I'd thought I'd give it a try if there's a fancy formula that I can use for a Calculated Field or if I could use InfoPath.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The only other option then is to use (serious) JS coding to program what the Workflow would have doen.

Usually allowing SharePoint Designer is cheaper than coding for a week